# How to use npm install with docker? Installing node_modules without installing npm

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I' m trying to run npm install without installing npm:

```
sudo docker run -it -v $PWD/../src:/usr/src/app node:latest npm install
```

However I don't know where the `WORKDIR` of `node:latest` is located. I want `node_modules` installed in the folder `$PWD/../src`. I also don't want to create a dockerfile just for that.

Comment: That requirement doesn't make sense, any more than trying to ask Stack Overflow questions without using a Web browser does.  (You also can't really effectively use Docker for custom applications without writing Dockerfiles.)  Install the tools you need to get your job done.

Comment: @DavidMaze I don't see why it isn't possible. Many applications are dockerized so the person doesn't need to install it. Why wouldn' t it work? I' m mapping my project to the inside of this docker container, and it has npm installed. When I run npm on it, I should get the node_modules installed in the mounted volume, and then when the app exists, I still get the volume in the machine. I just need to know which workdir `node:latest` uses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a valid use case for using Docker where you just want to have a quick temporary environment to execute your scripts.

In case you do not know the `WORKDIR` of any image, you can still overwrite it when creating the container as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#workdir).

```
sudo docker run --rm -it \
  -w /any/directory \
  -v $PWD/../src:/any/directory \
  node:latest \
  npm install
```

**NOTE** I added the flag `--rm` so that the container will automatically be cleaned up once the `npm install` command finishes running.